# Refreshing div without page reload with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh

I'm using the following code to refresh the div that contains the comments but there's something that's not working like it should.

After 60 seconds it refreshes the div and after refresh it displays a 0(flickering around every 10 sec or something like that), instead of the comment list updated. I have no idea..

Nothing spotted by inspecting the source page, no error.

[image]

```
function ajax_com(){
  var xmlHttp;
  try{   
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }catch (e){
    try{
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
    }catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e){
            alert("No AJAX!?");
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    document.getElementById("tble").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    setTimeout('ajax_com()',60000);
  }
  var data = "action=ajax_com";
  xmlHttp.open("POST","http://wwwsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",true);
  xmlHttp.send(data);
}
window.onload=function(){
  setTimeout('ajax_com()',60000);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the html to the question please?

Comment: <table id="tble"><tr>comment 1</tr><tr>comment2</tr>

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `xmlHttp.responseText` is `0` or is empty.

Your ajax is not returning any data or is it? Try to use `Firebug` to see if it actually returns any data. Plus the data returned might be structured so you have to parse the response data and display comments accordingly with different attributes like poster name, picture, actual comment etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's your use of `onreadystatechange` this method is triggered on multiple state changes.

You'll want to check for the **4th** state on the `xmlHttp.readyState` property which is the **finished** state like so:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
    document.getElementById("tble").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    setTimeout('ajax_com()',60000);
  }
}
```

You might also like to check on the `xmlHttp.status` that it is 200 like this:

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Well, I've added what sh0ber said and I got no refresh. After I've added your code I it refreshes again but it still ouputs the 0

Comment: As Jay Patel suggested, try using firebug. If you're unsure how to use it then just add alert(xmlHttp.responseText); just before the "if" statement.

Comment: First time it returns empty second time 0, I was scouting google for solutions but I don't see any so far

Comment: ok do the same then but with alert(xmlHttp.status); and tell me what you get

Comment: After trying different things I've saw that the code works. I've replaced "http://wwwsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" with the actual page where Im trying to implement this code like in "mysite.com/news" but now in the div Im trying to refresh I get the whole page "news" refreshing and working without hole page to refresh, still I dont know what to do